# Eloquently give object properties with same name as variables in scope

Tags: php, zend-framework, scope

I'm using the Zend framework and I'm getting tired of having to specify as a property each and every variable I want to pass to the view.

Example:

```
$view = new Zend_View;
$view->userName = $userName;
$view->emailAddress = $emailAddress;
$view->isLoggedIn = $isLoggedIn;
...
```

Is there a concise/eloquent way to give an object properties from specified in-scope variables?

What I wish:

```
createProperties($view, [$userName, $emailAddress, $isLoggedIn]);
// does the same thing as the first example
```

Comment: This type of question doesn't have technically correct answer and probably would attract more opinions than anything else.